# how to create dynamic ref names in a loop REACTjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have 6 refs:

```
    const element0 = useRef(null)
    const element1 = useRef(null)
    const element2 = useRef(null)
    const element3 = useRef(null)
    const element4 = useRef(null)
    const element5 = useRef(null)
```

and i have a component which is being created in a loop: (component below is simplified)

```
             {documents.map((offer,i)=>(

                        <div ref={element...}> ////here is the problem. idk how to properly name ref in order to create references to all refs at the top.
                            <img src="......"/>
                        </div>
                    )
                )}
```

i tried to do it in many ways:

```
  <div ref={`element${i}`}>
  <div ref={element[i]}>
```

but it does not work ):

Comment: `const elements = [useRef(null), useRef(null), ...]` — Use an array, not individual variables.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you can store all elements in one `ref`, as you can see the below code.

```
const elementRef = useRef([]);

{documents.map((offer,i)=>(
        <div ref={ref => {
          elementRef.current[i] = ref
        }}>
        <img src="......"/>
     </div>
   )
)

}
```

Answer (score 1):

You probably want to use the package use-dynamic-refs

```
npm i use-dynamic-refs
```

then you want to import useDynamicRefs into your code like that:

```
import useDynamicRefs from 'use-dynamic-refs';
```

and inside your functional component:

```
const [getRef, setRef] = useDynamicRefs();
```

at this point, you can simply do the following:

```
documents.map((offer,i)=>(
   // Use i or any other "id" that for you is easy to be retrieved later
   <div ref={setRef(i)}> 
      <img src="......"/>
   </div>
 )
)}
```

and at last, retrieve the refs by using getRef:

```
const myRef = getRef("my-index")
```

For more information, this is the npm page of the package used: https://www.npmjs.com/package/use-dynamic-refs

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `array` of `ref`s

```
const elementRefs = useRef([])

useEffect(() => {
   elementRefs.current = elementRefs.current.slice(0, documents.length);
}, [documents]);


{documents.map((offer,i)=>(

                    <div 
                       key={i} 
                       ref={el => elementRefs.current[i] = el} >
                        <img src="......"/>
                    </div>
                )
            )}
```